# What files should I upload to WordPress for an asp.net program?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

Part of my group project is to have a word press page that has a button that you can click which will go to a aspx page. I created the asp.net database program and am ready to upload it to word press. What files should i upload in order to make a button that can direct to a functioning aspx page? Any help is appreciated we have little guidance on how to do this.

[image: Wordpress]

[image: Main directory]

[image: inside directory]

Comment: WordPress is PHP - a completely separate web-application platform and it's unwise to mix them both in the same website. Are you sure you understand your task correctly?

Comment: yes how he showed it to the class  theres a Word press page then he clicks a button and it opens the aspx program in another web page

Comment: Just because it opens it in another page doesn't mean you need them in the same site. They should probably be hosted on separate sites. They can still link to each other via hyperlinks if necessary.

Comment: As far as figuring out what to deploy for an ASP.NET site, have you checked out Visual Studio's built in publish functionality? It will generate a nice package for you containing the resources it needs to run.